# How to update MySQL with an ODBC command?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp, odbc

I've got an issue with updating a `MySQL` database. I've managed to save data initially, but the `UPDATE` code is not working.

```
Private Sub BTNSimpan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTNSimpan.Click

    Dim ctgllhr As String
    Dim cmbtgl As String
    Dim ctptgl As String

    ctgllhr = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    cmbtgl = CBOMB.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    ctptgl = CBOTGL_PEMB.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Dim fotoktp() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathFilektp)
    Dim fotottd() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathFilettd)

    Try
        CMD.Connection = konek
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        CMD.CommandText = "select * from e_ktp where ID_E_KTP='" & txtidktp.Text & "'"
        DR = CMD.ExecuteReader


        If DATABARU Then
            konek.Close()

        Else
            konek.Close()
            konek.Open()

            pesan = MsgBox("Apakah Anda Yakin Data Akan ditambahkan ke Database ?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Perhatian")
            If pesan = vbYesNo Then
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Dim simpan As String = "INSERT INTO `e_ktp` (`ID_E_KTP`, `NIK`, `NAMA`, `TEMPAT`, `TANGGAL_LAHIR`, `JENIS_KELAMIN`, `ALAMAT`, `RT`, `RW`, `KEL_DESA`, `KECAMATAN`, `AGAMA`, `STATUS_PERKAWINAN`, `PEKERJAAN`, `KEWARGANEGARAAN`, `MASA_BERLAKU`, `KOTA_KTP`, `FOTO_KTP`, `PROVINSI_KTP`, `TTD_KTP`, `TANGGAL_PEMBUATAN`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

            Dim sp As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(simpan, konek)
            'sp.Parameters.Add("ID_E_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtidktp.Text
            'sp.Parameters.Add("FOTO_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary, foto.Length).Value = foto

            sp.Parameters.Add("ID_E_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtidktp.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("NIK", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtnik.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("NAMA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtnama.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("TEMPAT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txttempat.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("TANGGAL_LAHIR", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = ctgllhr
            sp.Parameters.Add("JENIS_KELAMIN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cboJK.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("ALAMAT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtalamat.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("RT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBORT.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("RW", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBORW.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("KEL_DESA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKEL.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("KECAMATAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKEC.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("AGAMA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOAGM.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("STATUS_PERKAWINAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKAWIN.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("PEKERJAAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOPKR.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("KEWARGANEGARAAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cbokwg.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("MASA_BERLAKU", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cmbtgl
            sp.Parameters.Add("KOTA_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cbokota.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("FOTO_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary, fotoktp.Length).Value = fotoktp
            sp.Parameters.Add("PROVINSI_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOPROV.Text
            sp.Parameters.Add("TTD_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary, fotottd.Length).Value = fotottd
            sp.Parameters.Add("TANGGAL_PEMBUATAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = ctptgl
            sp.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Sukses simpan")

        End If

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        DataGridView1.Refresh()
        isigrid()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally

    End Try

End Sub
```

I can't update to `MySQL` in same way:

```
    Dim ctgllhr As String
    Dim cmbtgl As String
    Dim ctptgl As String

    ctgllhr = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    cmbtgl = CBOMB.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    ctptgl = CBOTGL_PEMB.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    Dim fotoktp() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathFilektp)
    Dim fotottd() As Byte = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PathFilettd)

    pesan = MsgBox("Anda yakin data ini akan di update ?", vbYesNo + vbInformation, "Perhatian")
    If pesan = vbYesNo Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim update As String = "UPDATE `e_ktp` set (`NIK`, `NAMA`, `TEMPAT`, `TANGGAL_LAHIR`, `JENIS_KELAMIN`, `ALAMAT`, `RT`, `RW`, `KEL_DESA`, `KECAMATAN`, `AGAMA`, `STATUS_PERKAWINAN`, `PEKERJAAN`, `KEWARGANEGARAAN`, `MASA_BERLAKU`, `KOTA_KTP`, `FOTO_KTP`, `PROVINSI_KTP`, `TTD_KTP`, `TANGGAL_PEMBUATAN`)  WHERE ID_E_KTP = '" & TXTIDKTP.Text & "' VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    Dim up As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(update, konek)
       up.Parameters.Add("NIK", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txtnik.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("NAMA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = TXTNAMA.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("TEMPAT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = txttempat.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("TANGGAL_LAHIR", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = ctgllhr
    up.Parameters.Add("JENIS_KELAMIN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cboJK.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("ALAMAT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = TXTALAMAT.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("RT", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBORT.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("RW", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBORW.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("KEL_DESA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKEL.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("KECAMATAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKEC.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("AGAMA", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOAGM.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("STATUS_PERKAWINAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOKAWIN.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("PEKERJAAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOPKR.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("KEWARGANEGARAAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cbokwg.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("MASA_BERLAKU", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cmbtgl
    up.Parameters.Add("KOTA_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = cbokota.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("FOTO_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary, fotoktp.Length).Value = fotoktp
    up.Parameters.Add("PROVINSI_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = CBOPROV.Text
    up.Parameters.Add("TTD_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Binary, fotottd.Length).Value = fotottd
    up.Parameters.Add("TANGGAL_PEMBUATAN", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = ctptgl
    up.Parameters.Add("ID_E_KTP", Odbc.OdbcType.Text).Value = TXTIDKTP.Text
    up.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Sukses update")

    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
    isigrid()
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Comment: You did not describe a problem or an error; please read [Ask] and take the [Tour].  Saving dates as strings is a pretty bad start though.  Why are you using ODBC instead of the MySql Provider?

Comment: Your `Update` syntax is incorrect. `... Set col1 = par1, col2 = par2, ...`